# IFileDialog or SHBrowseForFolder: how to open showing contents of "Computer" and preferably not showing Desktop etc. on left?

Tags: mfc

Either version of this code works fine, but my disk utility only works on physical folders, not things like Workgroup.  Any way to limit it to things actual file system entities?

Here's my current IFileDialog version:

```
  IFileDialog *pfd;
  if ( CoCreateInstance( CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                         IID_PPV_ARGS( &pfd ) ) != S_OK ) {
       AKS( AKSWarn, "CoCreateInstance() failed" );
       return;
  }

  DWORD dwOptions;
  pfd->GetOptions( &dwOptions );
  pfd->SetOptions( dwOptions | FOS_PICKFOLDERS );

  if ( pfd->Show( NULL ) != S_OK ) {
      AKS( AKSWarn, "IFileDialog::Show() failed" );
      pfd->Release();
      return;
  }

  IShellItem *psi;
  if ( pfd->GetResult( &psi ) != S_OK ) {
      AKS( AKSWarn, "IFileDialog::GetResult() failed" );
      pfd->Release();
      return;
  }

  LPWSTR pwcsChoice;
  if ( psi->GetDisplayName( SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING,
                            &pwcsChoice ) != S_OK ) {
      AKS( AKSWarn, "IFileDialog::GetResult() failed" );
      psi->Release();
      pfd->Release();
      return;
  }

  char szChoice[ 500 ];
  wcstombs( szChoice, pwcsChoice, sizeof( szChoice ) );
  peditRoot->SetWindowText( szChoice );

  CoTaskMemFree( pwcsChoice );
  psi->Release();
  pfd->Release();
```

The SHBrowseForFolder() is called with a wrapper function I got from MSFT website:

```
static bool GetFolder( string& folderpath, const char* szCaption = NULL, 
                       HWND hOwner = NULL ) {
   bool retVal = false;

   // The BROWSEINFO struct tells the shell 
   // how it should display the dialog.
   BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 };

   bi.ulFlags   = BIF_USENEWUI;
   bi.hwndOwner = hOwner;
   bi.lpszTitle = szCaption;

   // must call this if using BIF_USENEWUI
   ::OleInitialize( NULL );

   // Show the dialog and get the itemIDList for the 
   // selected folder.
   LPITEMIDLIST pIDL = ::SHBrowseForFolder( &bi );

   if ( pIDL ) {
      char szBuf[_MAX_PATH] = { '\0' };
      if ( ::SHGetPathFromIDList( pIDL, szBuf ) ) {

         // Set the string value.
         folderpath = szBuf;
         retVal     = true;
      } else
      SCWinUtilMessageBoxVA( hOwner, "Error Browsing", MB_OK,
                "This app can only work with actual disks or folders, not "
                "Control Panel, Workgroup, etc." );


      // free the item id list
      CoTaskMemFree( pIDL );
   }

   ::OleUninitialize();

   return retVal;
}
```

Stack overflow is complaining I provided too much code.  So I have to add some text at the bottom to pad it out, apparently.  Stack overflow is complaining I provided too much code.  So I have to add some text at the bottom to pad it out, apparently.  Stack overflow is complaining I provided too much code.  So I have to add some text at the bottom to pad it out, apparently.  Stack overflow is complaining I provided too much code.  So I have to add some text at the bottom to pad it out, apparently.

Comment: FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM looks like what you want.

Comment: _"Stack overflow is complaining I provided too much code."_ -- Then you should propably think about it instead of cheating the system. Most of the code you are showing isn't relevant to the question. The question is about *showing* the dialog, not about evaluation of the result.

Comment: The famous Raymond Chen, thx.  Yes, that's what I want.  It's a surprisingly crap implementation though: still shows me all the non-filesystem "locations," but if I hit the "select folder" button (in effect the OK button) on the dialog after selecting one of the non-disk/folders, it shows the cryptic message "You can't open this location using this program.  Please try a different location."   That smacks of the app requesting a choice and user must obey, whereas in fact user hit the Browse button.  I think my own dialog (see code) is at least a bit better despite dialog already being closed.

Comment: It shows the non-filesystem locations because there may be a filesystem location as a subfolder. For example, "This PC" is not a file system location, but you can expand it to get to your C: drive, which *is* a file system location.